# How to open .doc file having html content as input in Android?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, doc

I am generating a .doc file on the fly having HTML content as input in C#. **The problem is when I open this file in android tablet then it is displaying the HTML content in plain text with all html tags.**
But if upload a .doc file created in ms-word and making its content bold, italic and changing its colors and fonts then android does not have any problem to open it as it is. **It has only problem when I am generate the .doc file on the fly having HTML content.**

This is the [link where I am generating my word document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7341/Dynamically-generate-a-MS-Word-document-using-HTML).

Thanks!